# How does one specify a section-like entity without a title in a docbook article?

Tags: docbook

I have an article that I'm converting to Docbook format. The article contains small lightweight sections that group together a few (simple) paragraphs. The sections do not contain titles.

I cannot find an element in Docbook that denotes this structure. All section-like elements I've found require a title.

A close example of what I want to do is like how in a chapter or short story sometimes to denote a break in setting, two paragraphs will be separated by blank lines or ** * ** or some other visual cue connoting discontinuation. I looked at the *book* element to see how this would implemented in a book but couldn't find any suitable element there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Would [`bridgehead`](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/bridgehead.html) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210314142415/https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/bridgehead.html)) as a separator between paragraphs, work? For example, `<bridgehead>** * **</bridgehead>`.

I realize that's not the same as a title-less section-like container, but I believe it's the closest DocBook gets to what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

> Would [`bridgehead`](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/bridgehead.html) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210314142415/https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/bridgehead.html)) as a separator between paragraphs, work? For example, `<bridgehead>** * **</bridgehead>`.

This appears to be what I want. In reading the DocBook documentation for the [bridgehead](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/bridgehead.html) element, I see that DocBook isn't so much designed to do old-fashioned, non-hierarchical layouts.

> Some documents, usually legacy
> documents, use headings that are not
> tied to the normal sectional
> hieararchy. These headings may be
> represented in DocBook with the
> [`bridgehead`](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/bridgehead.html) element.
>
> Bridge heads may also be useful in
> fiction or journalistic works that
> don't have a nested hierarchy.

But such legacy documents are at least supported. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!